Can the nature of Normal Reaction be predicted beforehand for any mechanical set-up?
Is it true that it is possible to predict the nature of Normal Reaction ( magnitude, direction, etc. ) in any mechanical set-up without first solving the dynamical equations of motion and constraints? I mean that whether we can predict the nature of Normal Reaction intuitively beforehand.


[Is it] possible to predict the nature of Normal Reaction ( magnitude, direction, etc. ) in any mechanical set-up without first solving the dynamical equations of motion and constraints?

Yes, it is certainly possible. Take an object with mass $m$ in a lift that is accelerating with a known acceleration $a(t)$ where we take a positive acceleration as being upwards. Let's also assume that $a(t) > -g$. We know that the net force on the  object must be $ma(t)$, so we have
$N - mg = ma(t)
\\ \Rightarrow N = mg + ma(t)$
We do not need to solve the equation of motion
$\displaystyle \frac {d^2 x}{dt^2} = a(t)$
in order to find $N$.
